# Using composer to install event-dispatcher fails on the directory structure

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I'm trying to use composer to install Symfony Component Event-dispatcher, but the component is installed under the 
                  directory vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher , is this normal?

My Object class is requiring
application/../library/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /library/Far/Resource/EventDispatcher.php on line 41

I also am requiring the composer autoload.php

What am I doing wrong?

composer.json

```
{
    "name": "odnanref/DocsisManager",
    "license": "GPL2",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "Docsis Manager WebApp software",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "library/" }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "zendframework/zendframework1": "1.*",
                "symfony/event-dispatcher": "*"
    },
        "authors":[
                {
                        "name": "Fernando Andre",
                        "email": "xxx@localhost.localdomain"
                }
        ],
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable"
}
```

cat public/index.php

```
<?php

// Define path to application directory
defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
    || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application'));

// Define application environment
defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
    || define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'production'));

// Ensure library/ is on include_path
/*
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
     realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
     realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../vendor/zendframework/zendframework1/library'),
     get_include_path()
)));
*/
require_once realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../vendor/autoload.php');

/** Zend_Application */
require_once 'Zend/Application.php';

// Create application, bootstrap, and run
$application = new Zend_Application(
    APPLICATION_ENV,
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
);
$application->bootstrap()
            ->run();
```

Comment: _is this normal?_ - yes, it is. Unless you changed it manually. Can we see your `composer.json`? Have you already tried to `composer update` to rebuild the autoloader?

Comment: how did you called `EventDispatcher`? if you put `var_dump(spl_autoload_functions());` at the very end of `index.php`, what's the output?

Comment: my mistake, I'm using a require statement , this is code from 3 years ago I forgot about how this was being done and didn't bother to check. My Bad